# Android: Upgrading API for "Move to SD Card" option

Tags: android, api, sd-card

I currently have an app that was built around the 1.6 API. It has begun to accrue size and currently is quite large. I was wondering if I upgrade to API 2.2, add: `android:installLocation="auto"` to the manifest, but set `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="6" />` if I will lose users that have lower then 2.2. Currently 1.6 users account for less than 1% of users but 2.1 accounts for 10%. Losing 1.6 wouldn't be a problem but I don't think the benefit of using the SD card would outweigh losing 10% of my users.

Let me know what you think.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't lose the 1.6 users if you add `android:installLocation="auto"` and set the min SDK to 6. You'll have to build with the 2.2 SDK. When you are adding new code you have to make sure that you use 1.6 methods, otherwise it will build without errors and crash on the devices with Android Version smaller than 2.2.

Comment: Thank you, I just confirmed it on the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `installLocation` will only affect users who have versions that support that setting: folks from earlier revisions will still be able to install the software.

Comment: what about changing the API from 1.6 to 2.2 ?

Comment: Change the target, not the min: `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="8" />`.